# Are Meridians really parallel lines?

Tags: geometry

It is generally agreed that longitude lines are parallel lines curved by a curved surface but can I question that?

- Consider a flat surface as flat as an Ice-rink , if you start two parallel lines an then aim at the same point the lines are intentionally bending them and they are no longer no more parallel. If you start at the Equator with 2 parallel lines and head North, not toward the North Pole, the lines will never meet and pass along the pole: just think of a real railroad with a gauge of a big-at-will value, say 100 miles or whatever
- To uphold this view, consider that this idea is already implemented on the same sphere calle Earth, when you rotate it by 90° and they are actually calle Parallels:
  [image]

Conclusions: *two parallel lines are possible even on a curved surface, surely on a cylinder, but also on a sphere*

Can you correct, please, what is wrong about that statement?

P.S. if something is wrong, kindly point that out and correct, if you downvote you discourage viewers to read this interesting, even if incorrect, question

Comment: Usually "parallel lines" is meant for lines which don't meet. Meridians meet at the poles, so they cannot be considered parallel under this definition. The problem here is: what do we mean by "parallel lines" in a curved surface?

Comment: @Crostul, the picture shows the answer

Comment: According to your picture, then, meridians are not parallel.

Comment: @Crostul, that's exactly the point of my post, thanks for the vote

Answer (score 1):

We need to agree what *lines* means on the surface of a sphere.

If we define, as usually done, lines as trajectories that minimize the distance between two points it is well known that the lines are the maximal circles, namely those circles on the surface cut by planes through the center of the sphere.

Any two such lines meet, in fact at two antipodal points.

If you take as definition of lines something else, well, anything can happen.

Comment: a line is a straight line  and can bend on the z axis and still be straight on the xy plane. The mistake they made is to assume that two parallel lines on that plane cannot bent on the vertical direction, as , I showed, it happens on a cylinder. Parallels on earth are the true parallel lines on the Earth, Meridians bend vertically AND horizontally, but not because of geodesics but because we make them do , wanting them to converge to one single point, right?

Comment: @user157860: No, I guess not. Meridians are great circles and they do intersect. Paralleles (same latitude curves) indeed do not meet, but they are not "lines", except the Equator.

Comment: Thanks, my question was triggered by this passage:"* If you fire off two parallel lines at the North pole, they move away from each other, following the topology of the Earth and then come back together.*" here https://phys.org/news/2017-06-universe-flat-topology.html#:~:text=And%20for%20it%20to%20maintain,1%C3%971057%20parts.. I know it is not true but on whose authority can I refute that?